# BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials - Unable to resolve the error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

I was hoping to get some help with this error code I have been coming across.

**Context**:

- The company I work for use the GSUITE product.
- My team have their own Cloud Project setup.
- Google Drive isn't a "personal" drive.
- We utilise Airflow to refresh our BigQuery tables on a
  daily/weekly/monthly basis.

I have followed these solutions

[Access Denied: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598784/access-denied-permission-denied-while-getting-drive-credentials)

["Encountered an error while globbing file pattern" error when using BigQuery API w/ Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731823/encountered-an-error-while-globbing-file-pattern-error-when-using-bigquery-api)

And also referenced
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#python_3

**Problem**

Cloud Composer : v 1.12.0

I have recently setup an external Bigquery table that reads a tab within a Google Sheet. My Airflow DAG has been failing to complete due to the access restriction to Drive.
I have added the following to the Airflow connection scopes:

[airflow scopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JddVe.png)

And also added the service account e-mail address to the Google Sheet the table is referencing via Share. I have also updated the Service account IAM roles to BigQuery admin. After following these steps, I still receive the error BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.

---

**Problem2**

Following the above, I found it easier to trouble shoot in local, so I created a VENV on my machine because its where im most comfortable troubleshooting. The goal is to simply query a Bigquery table that reads a Google sheet. However, after following the same above steps, I am still unable to get this to work.

My local code:

```
import dotenv
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
import google.auth

def run_BigQuery_table(sql):
    dotenv.load_dotenv()
    credentials, project = google.auth.default(
        scopes=[
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery",
        ]
    )
    bigquery.Client(project, credentials)
    output = pd.read_gbq(sql, project_id=project, dialect='standard')
    return output

script_variable = "SELECT * FROM `X` LIMIT 10"

bq_output = run_BigQuery_table(script_variable)
print(bq_output)
```

**My error**:

> raise self._exception
> google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied > while getting Drive credentials.

> raise GenericGBQException("Reason: {0}".format(ex))
> pandas_gbq.gbq.GenericGBQException: Reason: 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission > denied while getting Drive credentials.

Is anyone able to help?

Cheers

Comment: Adding: credentials, project = google.auth.default(
        scopes=[
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery",
        ]
    ) did the trick for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

So a colleague suggested that I explore the default pandas_gbq credentials, as this might be using default credentials to access the data.

Turns out, it worked.

You can manually set the pandas-gbq credentials by following this:
https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/authentication.html
https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pandas_gbq.Context.credentials

I simply added the following to my code

```
pdgbq.context.credentials = credentials
```

The final output:

```
import dotenv
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
import google.auth
import pandas_gbq as pdgbq


def run_BigQuery_table(sql):
    dotenv.load_dotenv()
    credentials, project = google.auth.default(
        scopes=[
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery",
        ]
    )
    pdgbq.context.credentials = credentials
    bigquery.Client(project, credentials)
    output = pd.read_gbq(sql, project_id=project, dialect='standard')
    return output

script_variable4 = "SELECT * FROM `X` LIMIT 10"

bq_output = run_BigQuery_table(script_variable3)
print(bq_output)
```

Comment: For those who are wondering, this exact solution will work for the Client.query(query="some query") as well. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-auth-drive-scope#bigquery_auth_drive_scope-python

Answer (score 1):

I often get these errors, and the vast majority were solved through creating and sharing service accounts. However I recently had a case where our gsuite administrator updated security settings so that only our employees could access gsuite related things (spreadsheets, storage etc). It was an attempt to plug a security gap, but in doing so, any email address or service account which did not have @ourcompany.com was blocked from using BigQuery.

I recommend you explore your company gsuite settings, and see if external access is blocked. I cannot say this is the fix for your case, but it was for me, so could be worth trying..

Comment: Thanks for the advice, we are able to shared addresses that dont have @ourcompany.com, but a warning/notification is pops up prior to sharing.