# Bigquery error: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials. I have BQ Data Viewer/Editor role

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to run a simple query using the below query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `mytable`
```

Before I run the query I get this error: `Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.`

I have **BigQuery Data Viewer** and **Data Editor** role for that table.

[image]

Comment: This may be a duplicate ... see if this helps ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68064592/bigquery-permission-denied-while-getting-drive-credentials-unable-to-resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I was querying a table that is created from google sheets. That google sheet was not shared with me therefore I was not able to query it however the table was in a project and dataset to which I had data viewer and editor access.

Answer (score 1):

The table you are querying is an reference to an External Drive file. You will also need to give the BigQuery account you are using access to Google Drive

> [Drive permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-drive#:%7E:text=Enable%20Drive%20access,-Accessing%20data%20hosted&text=Follow%20the%20web%2Dbased%20authentication,Client%20Tools%20access%20to%20Drive.)
> At a minimum, to query external data in Drive you must be granted View access to the Drive file linked to the external table.