# Permission Denied Error When Accessing Google Drive via BigQuery Service Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, permissions, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I am encountering a persistent issue when trying to access data stored in Google Drive through a BigQuery external table using a service account. Despite having the Google Drive API enabled, the service account added to the Google Sheet and the service account set up, I keep receiving a permission denied error related to Drive credentials.

**Issue Description:**

When executing queries from an external application using the service account, I receive the following error:

> "Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting
> Drive credentials."

This error occurs consistently across different queries attempting to access the external table linked to a Google Shet source.

**Steps Taken:**

- Service Account Setup: The service account is created and used for
  querying.
- API Enablement: Google Drive API is enabled in the project.
- IAM Permissions: I attempted to add relevant permissions to the service account. However, I couldn't find roles specifically related to Google Drive (like roles/drive.file) in the IAM "Add permissions" window.
  -API Restrictions: I am unsure how to check for any API restrictions that might be applied to the service account or the project.

**Questions:**

- Missing Roles: Why can't I find the roles/drive.file or similar roles in the IAM permissions list? Is there a specific way to add Drive-related roles to a service account?
- API Restrictions: How can I check if there are any API restrictions at the project or organization level that might be affecting the service account's access to Google Drive?
- Alternative Solutions: If direct access continues to be an issue, what are the best practices for setting up a synchronization mechanism between BigQuery and an external Google Drive table?

Any insights or suggestions from the community would be greatly appreciated, as I've hit a roadblock with this issue.

Comment: Did you grant the service account email on the Drive directory (or file)?

Comment: IAM is part of Google Cloud. Google Drive is not part of Google Cloud. Those services use OAuth Scopes to request permissions. When creating the client with the service account, you must specify the Google Drive scope when creating the credentials (OAuth 2.0 Access Token). https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/api-specific-auth

Comment: Hi @Rupert Schiessl, Can you take a look at these [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74265388/17258510) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-drive#:%7E:text=Enable%20Drive%20access,-Accessing%20data%20hosted&text=Follow%20the%20web%2Dbased%20authentication,Client%20Tools%20access%20to%20Drive.)?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes, the service account has access to the file and the directory.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for your suggestion. 
I can't s see here to specify the Google Drive scope when I create a service account.
I have given a domain wide delegation to the SA for all drive, docs, spreadsheets and BQ resources.
I have also created an OAuth 2.0 Client ID with access to Drive and BQ APIs
For the moment I still get the same error message.

Comment: Scopes are not attached to a service account when you create it. They are specified as a parameter when you initialize the client (SDK) or when you create the Access Token. In other words, your code must request the permission (OAuth Scope).